# Sitecore MVC Ajax resource not found

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, sitecore, sitecore7

I have a clean install of Sitecore 7.5 with MVC and I am trying to do a simple Ajax call but I am getting a 404 at runtime. The controller rendering renders just fine but when I fire the Ajax call by selecting an option from the dropdown, I get the error:

GET [domain name url]/api/BookDetailsController/GetBookDetails 404 (Not Found)

Any help is much appreciated, thank you.

**RouteConfig.cs:**

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace Website.Routes
{
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "BookDetailsController",
            url: "api/BookDetailsController/GetBookDetails",
            defaults: new { controller = "BookDetailsController", action = "GetBookDetails" }
        );
    }
}
}
```

**Global.asax.cs:**

```
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace sc75rev141003
{
// Note: For instructions on enabling IIS6 or IIS7 classic mode, 
// visit http://go.microsoft.com/?LinkId=9394801
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        Website.Routes.RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }
}
}
```

**Simple View with Ajax call:**

```
@using System.Web.Mvc

Select Any Book :
@Html.DropDownList("Books")

<div id="BookDetail" style="white-space: pre;">

</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-2.1.1.js">      </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $("#Books").bind("keyup change", function () {
        var itemId = $(this).val();
        if (itemId != "") {
            $.getJSON("api/BookDetailsController/GetBookDetails",
                function(data) {
                    var BookString = "Book Title: " + data.BookTitle + "\n" + "Book Author: " + data.BookAuthor + "\n" + "Book Language:" + data.BookLanguage;
                    $("#BookDetail").text(BookString);
                    console.log("success", data);
                });
        }
        else {
            $("#BookDetail").text("");
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Were you able to fix this? does any of the answers help?

Answer (score 2):

Try reversing the routes order:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "BookDetailsController",
        url: "api/BookDetailsController/GetBookDetails",
        defaults: new { controller = "BookDetailsController", action = "GetBookDetails" }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

You should always put more specific routes in front. In your case it is the `api/{controller}/{action}/{id}` route pattern that matches the `api/BookDetailsController/GetBookDetails` url except that it doesn't find a controller called `BookDetailsControllerController`.

This being said your routes are not very RESTful. The idea of REST is that you have a resource (corresponding to your controller) and define different actions on it. So you would have a `BookingDetail` resource with a corresponding controller:

```
public class BookingDetailsController: ApiController
{
    public HttpResponseMessage Get()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

and then you would have a `GET /api/bookingdetails`:

```
$.getJSON('api/bookingdetails',
```

Now you just stick to the default routing definition where the action name is **NOT PART OF THE ROUTE**. In RESTful routes, the action name is inferred from the HTTP verb.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the good information provided, I've found that I've had more success injecting the routes into the Sitecore Pipeline than via the normal MVC routeconfig.

```
public class RegisterCustomRoutes
{
    public virtual void Process(Sitecore.Pipelines.PipelineArgs args)
    {
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }

    public bool MvcIgnoreHomePage { get; set; }

    protected virtual void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        if (MvcIgnoreHomePage){routes.IgnoreRoute(String.Empty);}
        /**********************************************************
         * For more info see:
         * http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc668201(v=vs.100).aspx
         **********************************************************/
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
                routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

routes.MapRoute(
        name: "BookDetailsController",
        url: "api/BookDetails/GetBookDetails",
        defaults: new { controller = "BookDetails", action = "GetBookDetails" }    
routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
    );
    }
}
```

Something like the above should do the trick. As was mentioned, you do not need the 'Controller' in the name, that's handled by the framework.

Then, include the following in your web.config (or better a patch):

```
    <pipelines>
      <initialize>
        <processor type="Yournamespace.RegisterCustomRoutes,Duke.Common.Infrastructure.SitecoreExtensions" patch:before="processor[1]">
          <mvcIgnoreHomePage>false</mvcIgnoreHomePage>
        </processor>
      </initialize>
</pipelines>
```

This wires the custom routing up. As has been mentioned as well, you want to go from more specific to more general in your routing order.

Answer (score 0):

Change the code in RouteConfig.cs to :

```cs
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace Website.Routes
{
   public class RouteConfig
   {
       public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
       {
           RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
               name: "BookDetailsController",
               routeTemplate: "api/BookDetailsController/GetBookDetails",
               defaults: new { controller = "BookDetailsController", action = "GetBookDetails" }

           );

       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to include Controller keyword with the Controller name.
Your route config should be:

```
routes.MapRoute(
        name: "BookDetailsController",
        url: "api/BookDetails/GetBookDetails",
        defaults: new { controller = "BookDetails", action = "GetBookDetails" }
    );
```

**It should also come before the generic route config**

And your ajax call should be:

```
$.getJSON("api/BookDetails/GetBookDetails",
                function(data) {
                    var BookString = "Book Title: " + data.BookTitle + "\n" + "Book Author: " + data.BookAuthor + "\n" + "Book Language:" + data.BookLanguage;
                    $("#BookDetail").text(BookString);
                    console.log("success", data);
                });
```